# How do I do something LIKE in mysql in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I wanted to check the user's expertise and display their network graph. The reason I wanted to use LIKE is because in mysql database the expertise attribute is included also with their workplace. For example: Data Analyst at Petronas. So I wanted to check if their expertise is data analyst and display their network graph.

This is the code that I've tried:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM professional, job, location WHERE PROFESSIONAL_ID LIKE '%$id%' AND PROFESSIONAL_ID=JOB_ID AND JOB_ID = LOCATION_ID " ;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo "
                <div class='card'>
                <img src='../images/img.png' style='width:100%'>
                <h2>".$row['PROFESSIONAL_NAME']."</h2>
                <p class='title'><i class='fa fa-briefcase' aria-hidden='true'></i> ".$row['JOB_NAME']."</p>
                <p class='marker'><i class='fa fa-map-marker' aria-hidden='true'></i> ".$row['LOCATION_NAME']."</p>
                <a href=".$row['PROFESSIONAL_URL']."><p><button>Contact</button></p></a>
              </div>

              <div class='network'> 
              <h2> Filter Network</h2>
              </div>

              <div class='filter'>
        <input type='radio' value='Expertise' unchecked name='radioBtn' onclick='checkexpertise(".$row['JOB_NAME'].")'> <label> Expertise</label><br>
        <input type='radio' value='Location' unchecked name='radioBtn' onclick='checklocation(".$row['LOCATION_NAME'].")'> <label> Location</label><br>
        <input type='radio' value='Workplace' unchecked name='radioBtn' onclick='checkworkplace()'> <label> Workplace </label><br>
        <input type='radio' value='Past Workplace' unchecked name='radioBtn' onclick='checkpast()'> <label>Past Workplace</label><br>

      </div>";


}

?>
<script>
      function CheckExpertise (Expertise) {
        if Expertise LIKE %Data Analyst% OR %data analyst%
        {
          window.location.replace("expertise.html");
          }
      }
      </script>
```

Comment: you should close your php tags before writing out html instead of echoing html. that's going to be a lot more error prone

Comment: In JavaScript you can use `includes` to see if the string contains another string. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: @jtylerm oh ya, thanks for reminding anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use `includes` and I'd recommend converted the string to all lowercase and then checking so you only have to do one check.

```
function CheckExpertise (Expertise) {
    if (Expertise.toLowerCase.includes("data analyst") {
        window.location.replace("expertise.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Idk why but I think there is something wrong at the onclick part radiobutton

Comment: can I do something like this, if I wanted to check their expertise? onclick='checkexpertise(".$row['JOB_NAME'].")'

Comment: @NurHidayah - JavaScript is case-sensitive. So, if the function name is `CheckExpertise`, you need to call it the same way: `onclick='CheckExpertise()`

Comment: okay thanks. but how do i take the input from php, and pass it to the function?

Comment: Looks like you're already doing that: ` onclick='CheckExpertise(".$row['JOB_NAME'].")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression for this:

```
if (/.*data analyst.*/i.test(Expertise)) {
  window.location.replace("expertise.html");
}
```

But please take a look at mysqli prepared statements and output sanitization (e.g. using htmlentities). Users can send anything as "id" including crafted SQL queries which you probably don't want to execute ;)

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM professional, job, location WHERE PROFESSIONAL_ID LIKE ? AND PROFESSIONAL_ID=JOB_ID AND JOB_ID = LOCATION_ID " ;
mysqli_bind_param($query, "s", "%{$id}%");
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($query);
```